# Keeping Up With Camera Frame Rate in Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, uvc

My goal is to display a real time feed from a USB camera in a Tkinter Window. My problem is that I can't seem to update the GUI fast enough to keep up with the frame rate of the camera. I'm interfacing with the camera using the [uvclite](https://github.com/Arksine/uvclite.git) python wrapper around the [libuvc](https://ken.tossell.net/libuvc/doc/) C library. uvclite is a lightweight ctypes wrapper around the underlying C library, so I don't think that piece is my bottleneck. Here is my code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import uvclite
import io
import queue

frame_queue = queue.Queue(maxsize=5)
# frame_queue = queue.LifoQueue(maxsize=5)
user_check = True

def frame_callback(in_frame, user):
    global user_check
    if user_check:
        print("User id: %d" % user)
        user_check = False
    try:
        # Dont block in the callback!
        frame_queue.put(in_frame, block=False)
    except queue.Full:
        print("Dropped frame!")
        pass

def update_img():
    print('getting frame')
    frame = frame_queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(io.BytesIO(frame.data)))
    panel.configure(image=img)
    panel.image = img
    print("image updated!")
    frame_queue.task_done()
    window.after(1, update_img)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with uvclite.UVCContext() as context:
        cap_dev = context.find_device()
        cap_dev.set_callback(frame_callback, 12345)
        cap_dev.open()
        cap_dev.start_streaming()

        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Join")
        window.geometry("300x300")
        window.configure(background="grey")

        frame = frame_queue.get(block=True, timeout=None)
        # Creates a Tkinter-compatible photo image, which can be used everywhere Tkinter expects an image object.
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(io.BytesIO(frame.data)))
        panel = tk.Label(window, image=img)
        frame_queue.task_done()
        panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")
        window.after(1, update_img)
        window.mainloop()

        print("Exiting...")
        cap_dev.stop_streaming()
        print("Closing..")
        cap_dev.close()
        print("Clear Context")
```

Each frame is a complete JPEG image, stored in a `bytearray`. The `frame_callback` function gets call for every frame generated by the camera. I see "Dropped frame!" printed quite frequently, meaning my GUI code isn't pulling frames off of the queue fast enough and `frame_callback` encounters the `queue.Full` exception when trying to put new frames onto the queue. I've tried playing with the delay on the `window.after` scheduled function (first integer argument, units of milliseconds), but haven't had much luck.

**So my question is:** What can I do to optimize my GUI code to pull frames off of the queue faster? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Read about [`Image.frombytes(...`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.frombytes). I feel your `frame_queue` can't deliver within **1 millisecond**.

Comment: What is the frame rate of the camera? I doubt it's 1000 frames per second, which is how often you're attempting to update the image.

Comment: I found a better way (inspired by @stovfl 's comment). I'm going to post it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer inspired by @stovfl's comment on the question, but I'm still curious to see how other people would approach this.

His comment pointed out that my `frame_queue` probably cannot deliver frames when calling `frame_queue.get()` within 1 millisecond, so I just removed the queue from the GUI update code entirely. Instead, I call the GUI updating code from the callback directly. Here is the new code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import uvclite
import io

user_check = True

def frame_callback(in_frame, user):
    global user_check
    if user_check:
        print("User id: %d" % user)
        user_check = False
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(io.BytesIO(in_frame.data)))
    panel.configure(image=img)
    panel.image = img

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with uvclite.UVCContext() as context:
        cap_dev = context.find_device()
        cap_dev.set_callback(frame_callback, 12345)
        cap_dev.open()
        cap_dev.start_streaming()

        window = tk.Tk()
        window.title("Join")
        window.geometry("300x300")
        window.configure(background="grey")
        panel = tk.Label(window)
        panel.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand="yes")

        window.mainloop()
        print("Exiting...")
        cap_dev.stop_streaming()
        print("Closing..")
        cap_dev.close()
        print("Clear Context")
```

This works quite well, and the GUI is very responsive and captures motion in real time. I'm not going to mark this as an answer just yet, I would like to see what other people come up with first.